# Best Pattern Applyable to Sudoku?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, sudoku

I'm trying to make a Sudoku game, and I gathered the following validations to each number inserted:

- Number must be between 1 and 9;
- Number must be unique in the line;
- Number must be unique in the column;
- Number must be unique in the sub-matrix.

As I'm repeating too much the "Number must be unique in..." rule, I made the following design:

- There are 3 kinds of groups, ColumnGroup, LineGroup, and SubMatrixGroup (all of them implement the GroupInterface);
- GroupInterface has a method `public boolean validate(Integer number)`;
- Each cell is related to 3 groups, and it must be unique between the groups, if any of them doesn't evaluate to true, number isn't allowed;
- Each cell is an observable, making the group an observer, that reacts to one Cell change attempt.

And that s*cks.
I can't find what's wrong with my design. I just got stuck with it.

Any ideas of how I can make it work?

Comment: Sounds a bit over-objectified, other than that it should work as a Sudoku solver. Also, you have not specified what exactly sucks?

Comment: Also, I wanna have the hability of making the grid extensible. For example, if I want to extend it to 1 .. 12, instead of 1 .. 9.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how could I make it easily verifiable, so I added a list of validators... And now I can't get out of it. Where is it over-objectified? I can feel it too, maybe there is another solution that would be more simple than that...

Comment: BTW: sudoku is easily defined as a set of SQL-constraints. But that wont solve it.

Answer (score 3):

> Where is it over-objectified? I can feel it too, maybe there is another solution that would be more simple than that...

Instead of having 3 validator classes, an abstract GroupInterface, an observable, etc., you can do it with a single function.

Pseudocode ahead:

```
bool setCell(int cellX, int cellY, int cellValue)
{
    m_cells[x][y] = cellValue;
    if (!isRowValid(y) || !isColumnValid(x) || !isSubMatrixValid(x, y))
    {
        m_cells[x][y] = null; // or 0 or however you represent an empty cell
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yep, but, if I wanted to make it 6x6 or 12x12? Would the function know everything about the game configuration?

Comment: Anyway, this is a nice and simple solution, if I don't find anything more, I'll try it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What is the difference between a ColumnGroup, LineGroup and SubMatrixGroup? IMO, these three should simply be instances of a generic "Group" type, as the type of the group changes nothing - it doesn't even need to be noted.

It sounds like you want to create a checker ("user attempted to write number X"), not a solver. For this, your observable pattern sounds OK (with the change mentioned above).

[Here (link)](http://pastebin.com/gwkxWWfb) is an example of a simple sudoku solver using the above-mentioned "group" approach.

Comment: In my first design I thought of making three different implementations of a validation method, that's why I needed the 3 groups...
But yet, this wasn't a nice approach. I'll study that code you gave me, thanks :)